# How to change executable name for a specific configuration in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I need dynamically change executable name for a compiled project (in VS 2015) depending of the configuration used.
E.g. in release mode the result must be release.exe, in debug mode - debug.exe.

I know that I can change `<AssemblyName>` in .csproj but the problem is that I must leave assembly name unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that I can change  in .csproj **but the problem is that I must leave assembly name unchanged.**

Since you must leave assembly name unchanged, you can try to add a copy target into your project to rename the executable name.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</project>`, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration).exe" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Delete Files="$(TargetPath)" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
  </Target>
```

If you also want rename other files in the output, you can change the custom target to:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration).exe" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe.config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration).exe.config" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).pdb" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(Configuration).pdb" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe.config" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).pdb" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>
</Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's nearly the same method I use (you just forgot checking of the configuration because I need the action only for a specific configuration)

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev, Yes, I did not know you are use this action for a specific configuration, so I am not add the condition. Now I have updated my answer, you can check if it works fine. If it works, you can accept it as answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Or you can share your solution here.